# How to turn off strict mode in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have problem with postgres, it's so different than mysql (type data string_numeric and numeric).

I have a query for a type column of type `varchar`.

Simple example

Table A

```
id(int) | kode(string) | name(string)
--------+--------------+-------------
1       |  2           | yuan
```

In mysql we can get data with

```
select * 
from A 
where kode = 2;
```

but in Postgres that is wrong SQL because type of data column `kode` is string, so must add ' to build query like

```
select * 
from A 
where kode = '2';
```

How to set Postgres to use the SQL like mysql does (turn off strict mode)?

Comment: My view is that you should learn to do things the postgresql way.

Comment: The best practice is when literal type matches the field datatype. PS. `select * from A where kode ='2';` is safe in MySQL too.

Answer (score 2):

you can cast your `column` in the condition as `INT`.

```
select * from A where kode::Int = 2;
```

I believe `postgresql` doesn't have `strict mode` option.

As suggested by Akina.

```
select * from A where kode= 2::varchar(30);
```